# UITextField leftView click event can not listen

Tags: ios, objective-c

Add a UIButton to UITextField's leftView, but found it impossible to listen for a click event when you click UIButton

code:

```
UIButton *cleanButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
[cleanButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clean_select_member"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cleanButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cleanSendMessageToUser)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.inputTextField.leftView = cleanButton;
self.inputTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
```

Comment: can you post cleanSendMessageToUser method ?

Comment: @AshishThakkar 
`- (void)cleanSendMessageToUser {
    self.inputTextField.leftView = nil;
    self.inputTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    self.inputTextField.placeholder = nil;
}`

Comment: you mean your method `- (void)cleanSendMessageToUser`   is not called when u click on button ?

Comment: @AshishThakkar  yes

Comment: May be given answer is right, it might be problem of touch area. have you tried by his answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution. 15 x 15 is very small and hard to touch.

I have given 30 x 30 though apple recommended minimum touch area is 44 x 44.

> Provide ample spacing for interactive elements. Try to maintain a
>   minimum tappable area of 44pt x 44pt for all controls.

```
UIButton *cleanButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[cleanButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clean_select_member"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cleanButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cleanSendMessageToUser)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.inputTextField.leftView = cleanButton;
self.inputTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
```

Comment: The problem is not the button can't clicked, then Click the button to trigger the [textField becomeFirstResponder]

Comment: @C.Bin when the button is clicked you want the textfield to become first responder right ?

Comment: i want to called the methods `-(void)cleanSendMessageToUser`

Comment: @C.Bin Please check this attached project.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9wvcgdx6993ux9/TextFieldLeftView.zip?dl=0